# JScrollpane on a jscrollpane-jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, layout-manager

I want to add multiple jscrollpane jpanels to a jscrollpane jpanel

After the 5 items i want to hide them. so I need to scroll to see them.

Is this possible? If yes, how do I do it?

[image: Print Screen]

Here is the code that I wrote to created to make my layouts, and testscenario.

So that should work just fine.

```
private void createLayout() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15, 15, 15, 15);
        for (int i = 0; i < subtitles.size() - 1; i++) {
            languageSelectionPanel.add(subtitles.get(i), gbc);
        }
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        startPanel.add(languageSelectionPanel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        startPanel.add(folderSelectedLabel, gbc);
        add(startPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);


        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            JPanel subtitlePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            subtitlePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
            JPanel subtitleHeader = new JPanel();
            JPanel subtitlesContent = new JPanel();

            GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
            gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 110, 200, 45, 17};
            gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
            gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
            gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
            subtitleHeader.setLayout(gridBagLayout);
            subtitlesContent.setLayout(gridBagLayout);

            JLabel lblImage = new JLabel("Download");
            lblImage.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
            GridBagConstraints gbc_lblImage = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_lblImage.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
            gbc_lblImage.gridx = 0;
            gbc_lblImage.gridy = 0;
            subtitleHeader.add(lblImage, gbc_lblImage);

            JLabel lblSkills = new JLabel("Skills");
            lblSkills.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
            GridBagConstraints gbc_lblSkills = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_lblSkills.gridx = 1;
            gbc_lblSkills.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
            gbc_lblSkills.gridy = 0;
            subtitleHeader.add(lblSkills, gbc_lblSkills);

            JLabel lblExp = new JLabel("Exp");
            lblExp.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
            GridBagConstraints gbc_lblExp = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_lblExp.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
            gbc_lblExp.gridx = 2;
            gbc_lblExp.gridy = 0;
            subtitleHeader.add(lblExp, gbc_lblExp);

            JLabel lblLevel = new JLabel("Level");
            lblLevel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
            GridBagConstraints gbc_lblLevel = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_lblLevel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
            gbc_lblLevel.gridx = 3;
            gbc_lblLevel.gridy = 0;
            subtitleHeader.add(lblLevel, gbc_lblLevel);

            JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
            GridBagConstraints gbc_separator = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_separator.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc_separator.gridwidth = 4;
            gbc_separator.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
            gbc_separator.gridx = 0;
            gbc_separator.gridy = 1;
            subtitleHeader.add(separator, gbc_separator);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Dit is nr: " + (i+1));
                GridBagConstraints gbc_label = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc_label.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
                gbc_label.gridx = 0;
                gbc_label.gridy = i;
                subtitlesContent.add(label, gbc_label);

                JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Tweede");
                GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc_lblNewLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
                gbc_lblNewLabel.gridx = 1;
                gbc_lblNewLabel.gridy = i;
                subtitlesContent.add(lblNewLabel, gbc_lblNewLabel);

                JProgressBar progressBar_1 = new JProgressBar();
                progressBar_1.setStringPainted(true);
                progressBar_1.setString("Testje" + "/");
                GridBagConstraints gbc_progressBar_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc_progressBar_1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                gbc_progressBar_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
                gbc_progressBar_1.gridx = 2;
                gbc_progressBar_1.gridy = i;
                subtitlesContent.add(progressBar_1, gbc_progressBar_1);

                JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("1");
                GridBagConstraints gbc_label_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc_label_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
                gbc_label_1.gridx = 3;
                gbc_label_1.gridy = i;
                subtitlesContent.add(label_1, gbc_label_1);
            }

            subtitlePanel.add(subtitleHeader, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            subtitlePanel.add(subtitlesContent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            centerPanel.add(subtitlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            JScrollPane centerScrollPane = new JScrollPane(centerPanel);
            centerScrollPane.setBorder(null);
            add(centerScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: I want to add multiple jscrollpane jpanels to a jscrollpane jpanel
After the 5 items i want to hide them. so I need to scroll to see them. Is this possible? If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: A lot will come down to the layout managers. You need to restrict the inner JScrollPane from been allowed to expand in size (beyond a given point), maybe making use of the Scrollable interface